# Add class to div depends the value of item of array

Tags: angular

I am trying to add a color on the left side of a text that depends on the value of one of the items in the array (type).
I have done the following, but it gives me this error: ERROR TypeError: can't access property "add", typeColor.classList is undefined

Anyone know if it can be done in another more optimal way or how to fix this problem?

```
    <div *ngFor="let item of array" class="c-block">
       <a [routerLink]="['/go', item.id]" class="c-block__content">
            <p class="c-block__type">
                <span class="c-block__type-color"></span>
                {{ item.type }}
            </p>
            <p class="c-block__text">{{ item.text }}</p>

        </a>
    </div>
```

.ts:

```
    array = [
    {
      id: '0',
      type: 'typeOne',
      text: 'Text one'
    },
    {
      id: '1',
      type: 'TypeSecond',
      text: 'Text two'
    },
  ];

    let typeColor = document.getElementsByClassName('c-block__type-color');

    if(this.array.indexOf((x: { type: string; }) => x.type === 'typeOne')){
      typeColor.classList.add('classOne');
    }
    else{
      typeColor.classList.add('classSecond');
    }
```

Comment: You should use the viewChild decorator whenever you want to query the Dom.  From the code, It doesn't look like you are in a class, that's a bit weird if it's angular.  The best way to add and remove classes is by using the ngClass directive

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `ngClass` or `[class.<class-name>]='truthy expression'`.No need of doing things manually.
Simple Example

```
<div *ngFor="let item of array" class="c-block">
   <a [routerLink]="['/go', item.id]" 
      [class.classOne]="item.type === 'typeOne'"
      [class.classTwo]="item.type === 'typeTwo'"> 
      {{ item.text }}
    </a>
</div>
```

Learn more about `ngClass` & `ngStyle` here
https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass/

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a NodeList not a single element. You have to loop through the list to add class.

There's an angular way to do this, using `[class.classname]="conditition"`

```
<div *ngFor="let item of array" class="c-block">
  <a [routerLink]="['/go', item.id]" class="c-block__content" [class.classOne]="item.type == 'typeOne'" [class.classSecond]="item.type != 'typeOne'">
    <p class="c-block__type">
      <span class="c-block__type-color"></span> {{ item.type }}
    </p>
    <p class="c-block__text">{{ item.text }}</p>

  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `ngClass` for the same.

```
  <div *ngFor="let item of array" class="c-block">
       <a [routerLink]="['/go', item.id]" class="c-block__content">
            <p class="c-block__type">
                <span class="c-block__type-color" [ngClass]="item.type === 'typeOne' ? 'classOne': 'classSecond'"></span>
                {{ item.type }}
            </p>
            <p class="c-block__text">{{ item.text }}</p>

        </a>
    </div>
```